# TFS, unable to unlock my own files

Tags: tfs, source-control-explorer, locked-files

I'm not sure how this has happened, I can't seem to unlock my own files:

[image]

Can't Undo or Unlock.  Please point me to any documentation I may have missed (although I've been googling for 30+ mins).  I imagine this is an experience thing.

Comment: It appears that you are not actually in the workspace where you have those checked out.  (Check in is also not enabled.)  Check the workspace picker drop down in source control explorer; make sure the workspace selected is the workspace with the pending changes.

Comment: You are correct, the workspace was wrong.  If you want to write an answer I'll happily accept.  Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This was caused through having the wrong workspace selected.